# Why use integer casting on process handle object for the 1st param of kernel32.TerminateProcess?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ctypes, windows-kernel

ok I'm doing some test on killing windows process using python binding of windows system calls, there are two methods I am using, but they are doing it different ly, some detail baffles me.

first approach is using ***win32api***

```
import win32api,subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen([ 'notepad' ])
win32api.TerminateProcess(proc._handle, -1)
```

second approach is using ***ctypes***

```
import ctypes, subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen([ 'notepad' ])
ctypes.windll.kernel32.TerminateProcess( proc._handle, -1 )
```

in the second approach, it will not work unless you integer cast the proc._handle like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([ 'notepad' ])
int_handle = int(proc._handle)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.TerminateProcess(int_handle, -1 )
```

this int_handle, presumably some sort of process handle number, usually values within 1-1000 on my machine.
by inspecting the proc._handle object using these builtins, I didn't get any terribly useful information:

```
print "dir() of handle >>",dir(proc._handle)    # ['Close', 'Detach']
print "type() of handle >>",type(proc._handle)  # <type '_subprocess_handle'>
```

Sysinternals handle.exe didn't give too much info as well.

```
notepad.exe pid: 8688 HOST\user
4: Event         
8: WaitCompletionPacket 
C: IoCompletion  
10: TpWorkerFactory 
14: IRTimer       
   ...
```

My question:

1. What excatly is this integer stored in int_handle?
2. why can it obtain the handle value doing a integer casting on proc._handle object?
3. and Why passing this number to kernel32.TerminateProcess?

Comment: @eryksun Sir, if you have an idea what is the number in int_handle, could you please elaborate it in an answer? if to you my question seems to lack due research, please point a direction for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the MSDN topic on [Handles and Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724457) for an overview of the various types of objects in the system and how handles are used to reference them. Kernel objects such as `Process` objects exist in kernel address space. User-mode programs cannot directly reference kernel memory. Instead each process has a kernel-object handle table that maps handle values such as 4, 8, 12 and so on to kernel objects. For example, when you call [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425), the call returns handles for the `Process` and its primary `Thread`.  You can also call [`OpenProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320) or [`OpenThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684335) to open a handle for an existing process or thread by ID. Call [`CloseHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211) to close a handle that's no longer needed.

(Kernel `File` objects, such as from calling `CreateFile`, are also referenced via handles. However, CPython uses the C runtime's low I/O file descriptors instead, such as 0, 1, 2 and so on, i.e.  Unix/POSIX file descriptors. On Unix everything is a file, whereas on Windows everything is an object. The C runtime maintains a private mapping of file descriptors to Windows `File` handles. Other object types are not mapped to Unix file descriptors. Using the low I/O file descriptors and C standard I/O makes it simpler to support both Unix and Windows. That said, there is at least one proposed patch with the ambitious goal of rewriting Python 3's I/O support on Windows to use the Windows API and `File` handles directly.)

---

In Python 2, subprocess uses a `_subprocess_handle` type on Windows to automatically close a handle when it's no longer referenced. This type defines an `__int__` method to support converting the handle value to an integer, but it doesn't subclass `int`, so it's not an integer itself. For your particular problem with ctypes, the default argument conversion only converts integer arguments to C `int` values, which is why you have to use `int(proc._handle)`.

However, using the default integer conversion is a mistake. You should define `TerminateProcess.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_uint)`. While real kernel handles are always in the 32-bit range, even on a 64-bit system, fake handles such as `(HANDLE)-1` (which is used to reference the current process without having to open a real handle) do use the full pointer range. Thus on 64-bit systems the upper `DWORD` of real kernel handles should be zero, and for pseudo-handles such as `(HANDLE)-1`, the non-zero upper `DWORD` must be preserved. In 2.x, ctypes doesn't zero the stack memory for arguments, and using the default C `int` type only writes the lower `DWORD` of the stack `QWORD`. For reliability you must either manually wrap arguments as pointers or define all `HANDLE` type arguments (including `HMODULE`, `HWND`, etc) as a pointer type such as `ctypes.c_void_p` or `wintypes.HANDLE`.

Using `ctypes.windll` is also problematic, since it caches DLLs, which cache function pointers. This leaves your script or module at the mercy of global state and can lead to conflicting `argtypes`, `restype`, and `errcheck` definitions. It also doesn't allow enabling the per thread protected storage for the last error value. Here's an example ctypes definition that's more reliable:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
kernel32.TerminateProcess.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.UINT)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import subprocess

    p = subprocess.Popen('notepad')       
    if not kernel32.TerminateProcess(int(p._handle), 1):
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
```